# What is better from an energy-saving perspective to run task minimum energy consumption

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, frequency, computation, energy

The **CPU frequency** and **CPU usage** are the main factors that impact energy consumption (as far as I know). however what is better from an energy-saving perspective to run task minimum energy consumption:

> *Option 1:* Maximum CPU frequency with minimum usage
>
> *Option 2:* Maximum CPU usage with min frequency.

Comment: Some BIOS let you set power limits on the CPU, then the CPU speeds up under load but only to the max where it optimizes work per energy.  After that the CPU slows itself down to wait for the next task.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that RISC processors, e.g. RISC V and ARM, tend to have better performance per watt than x86 processors for 'ordinary' tasks. The software available for them is more limited though.

Comment: @SimonGoater: The answer to this question is the same for any microarchitecture implementing any ISA.  I only mentioned x86 because I happen to have one in my desktop and watched that Intel talk so I know what the most-efficient frequency is.  But yes, certainly different CPUs have different best-case work/energy ratios, and not being x86 is intrinsically helpful in that.  Also, many non-x86 CPUs are designed and optimized with that as a higher priority than absolute peak performance, unlike say the Efficiency cores in Alder Lake.

Answer (score 2):

Work per time scales approximately linearly with CPU frequency.  (A bit less than linear because higher CPU frequency means DRAM latency is more clock cycles).

CPU power has two components: switching (dynamic) power which scales with f<sup>3</sup> (because voltage has to increase for higher frequency, and transistors switch are pumping that V^2 capacitor energy more often); and leakage power which doesn't vary as dramatically.  At high frequency dynamic power dominates, but as you lower the frequency, eventually it becomes significant.  The smaller your transistors, the more significant leakage is.

System-wide, there's also other power for things like DRAM that doesn't change much or at all with CPU frequency.

---

**Min frequency is more efficient**, unless the minimum is far below the best frequency for work per energy.  (Some parts of power decrease with frequency, others like leakage current and DRAM refresh don't).

Frequencies lower than max have lower work per energy (better task efficiency) up to a certain point.  Like 800 MHz on a Skylake CPU on Intel's 14 nm process.  If there's work to be done, there's no gain from dropping below that; just **race-to-sleep** at that most efficient frequency.  (Power would decrease, but work rate would decrease more below that point.)

https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/File:Intel_Architecture,_Code_Name_Skylake_Deep_Dive-_A_New_Architecture_to_Manage_Power_Performance_and_Energy_Efficiency.pdf is slides from IDF2015 about Skylake power management covered a lot of that general-case stuff well.  Unfortunately I don't know where to find a copy of the audio from Efraim Rotem's talk; it was up for a year or so after, but the original link is dead now. :/

Also in general about dynamic power (from switching, not leakage) scaling with frequency cubed if you adjust voltage as well as frequency, see [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) and

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614018/why-does-switching-cause-power-dissipation
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258724/why-do-cpus-need-so-much-current
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/548601/why-does-decreasing-the-cmos-supply-voltage-also-decrease-the-maximum-circuit-fr

Comment: They key to understanding "race to idle" is realizing that (most) modern CPUs do power gating (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_gating ). You can think of it as "race to stop leakage".

Comment: Note the OP talked about "energy consumption" and not power so giving the f² formula (provided by the linked docs) is certainly better suited here. This is implied by your first sentence but it certainly worth putting it explicitly.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Energy / work only scales approximately with f^2 if you assume that work/time is fully linear, and more importantly you assume you're operating in a regime where dynamic power totally dominates static (leakage) power.  Only dynamic power (with voltage at minimum for the frequency) scales with f^3.   But we're interested in an operating point where leakage power is non-negligible, lowering the frequency until it starts to be a problem.  (I didn't reread through all of each link just now; which one talks about work per energy? The IDF2015 Skylake slides?)

Comment: @JérômeRichard: I had a look at those IDF2015 slides.  Interesting formulation, of "compute energy" as just the dynamic component, scaling with f^2, and the "SoC and system energy" (static power for the time not clock-gated), scaling with 1/f + constant, since higher clocks mean more time sleeping with more parts powered down.  If I was more ambitious, I'd copy/paste those graphs and present it that way.  If you want to post an answer about that, or edit mine, feel free.